# When should I register my COM interface in HKCR\Interface?

Tags: windows, com, registry, com-interop

Turns out there's a HKCR\Interface subtree where I can register my newly introduced COM interface. As I get it I would need it in two cases:

- if I want to enable marshalling - then I can register proxy/stub there
- if I want to publish more information on my component so that other developers could lookup the interface id and find it's human-readable name under HKCR\Interface{InterfaceId}\Default value.

Are there any other scenarios I need to register my interface in HKCR\Interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A link to the interface's Type Library can be placed underneath the HKCR\Interface\IID subkey.  This is important if you want to support marshalling without having to write your own proxy.

If you are creating an OLE Automation Object, registering the Interface is also required in order for typesafe binding to work correctly in any Visual Basic app that wants to use your Object.